# ReactJS and HTM5 video tag presenting a strange behavior

Tags: html, reactjs, video

I have two React presentation components with HTML5 video tags.

This first one here

```
export default class Homepage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="Homepage">
        <Needs />
        <Mission />
        <Areas />
        <Products />
        <Duty />
        <Video />
        <Flag />
        <div className="video">
          <video autoPlay loop className="bg_video">
            <source src="resources/videos/arqui.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

works perfectly well. But this one

```
export default class Video extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="Video">
        <video autoPlay controls>
          <source src="resources/videos/sinapi.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

always fails. The video won't load.

[image: Here you may see how it fails.]

Everything else is fine. Both videos are under the same directory and I checked them: they are there and the names are correct. And they are both mentioned exactly the same way in the source property.

My static server is working fine, because all other images and videos are loading perfectly well.

The first video is being user as a background. And as you may see, the second one is laid over it. The `<Video />` tag in my JSX does this.

**Is there any known restriction to serve two videos at the same page or something like that?** This is the only thing I may think now.

Suggestions?

Comment: What error message the browser prints?

Comment: No message at all, @ArupRakshit. It just does not load and when I see the requests at the developer tools it says it failed but gives no reason at all. Just as the print I provided with the question. This is why I say it is strange.

Comment: If you replace the src path of the video that works with the one that doesn't work, then does it load? This honestly looks like a problem with your server serving the file. Even if the file physically exists something else must be wrong. Adding any error messages would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, @AndyNoelker. But as I commented above, no error messages are given, except for the one in the print I provided. I'll to the test you suggested.

Comment: I tested and you suggested, @AndyNoelker. And things continued the same. One of the videos would load, but not the other. And Google Chrome would say nothing but "failed". Then I tried Firefox and got a more interesting error message, explaining me the video encoding was wrong and the browser couldn't load it. Then I used a conversion software and now it is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came up that the problem was the video encoding. For some reason the conversion from Matroska to MP4 that I did when I downloaded the video from my customer's old website, resulted in some kind of problem. I inspected the payload of the request's result and noticed that the video was loaded but the browser was failing in exhibiting it.

Thanks for all suggestions.